# Page Redirect not Working on Node Js and React JS on Simple Login Using Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a simple login form using React and NodeJs with connected to Mysql DB. The problem is redirect is not working. I am adding redirect method and API in server.js and fetch method in loginpage.js as view below:

```
// API in server.js
/sales login
app.post('/login', jsonParser, (req, res) => { //jsonParser,
    let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  console.log("req: ",req.body);
    if (username && password) {
        dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username = ? AND password = ?`, [username, password], (err, results, fields) => {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.username = username;
        res.redirect('/home');
        console.log(results)
        console.log("req: ", req.body);
            } else {
                res.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.loggedin) {
        res.send('Welcome back, ' + req.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        res.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    res.end();
});
```

in loginpage.js, the code looks like :

```
async SubmitLogin(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state)
  await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
  })
  .then ((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    if (result.Status === 'Invalid')
      alert('Invalid User');
      else
        this.props.history.push({ Home });
        alert('Login Sucessfull');
  })
  .then ((body) => {
    console.log(body);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    return console.log();
  })

  alert('Test Submit Login')
}
```

I already tried the connection using postman, and there is no error. And I also tried sending username and password from loginpage.js is also no problem. The result displayed in my terminal:

[image]

Hopefully, I can get answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your client side, you are doing this:

```
this.props.history.push({ Home });
```

But push() expect route. So you should provide '/home' or something like that depending on how you defined routes in your react application.

example: `this.props.history.push('/home'); //route to your Home component`

Update: You can try something like this. API code:

```
// API in server.js
/sales login
app.post('/login', jsonParser, (req, res) => { //jsonParser,
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    console.log("req: ",req.body);
    if (username && password) {
        dbConn.query(`SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE username = ? AND 
                      password = ?`, [username, password],        
       (err, results, fields) => {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.username = username;
                res.redirect('/home');
                console.log(results)
                console.log("req: ", req.body);
            } else {
                res.send(401, 'Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }           
            res.end();
        });
    } else {
        res.send(401,'Please enter Username and Password!');
        res.end();
    }
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.loggedin) {
        res.send('Welcome back, ' + req.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        res.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    res.end();
});
```

In loginpage.js. Make changes as following:

```
async SubmitLogin(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state)
  await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
  })
  .then ((response) => {
    if(response.status == 401) {
        throw new Error('Unauthorized');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);

    this.props.history.push('/home');
    alert('Login Sucessfull');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })

  alert('Test Submit Login')
}
```

Hope this helps. I just made this workable. There are lots of improvements that can be made here.

Comment: I tried as you recommend  it,,, but also nothing happens

Comment: @Shinichi1988 can you let me know if you are seeing the 'Login Successful' alert box? If so, can you show me the code where you defined the routes in your React app?

Comment: I changed the code to this, and its working now. .then ((response) => {
    //return response.json();
    console.log(response)
      if(response === false){
      alert('Invalid User');
      console.log(response)
      alert('Invalid User');
      //this.props.history.push('/login');
    }
      else {
        alert('Login Sucessfull');
        this.props.history.push('/home');
      }
  })

but the problem is, when we input the wrong username, its also appear the home page

Comment: thanks @Zaman the code is working in server but not in frontend. I got 401 error status

Comment: the code worked @Zaman... I comment //return response.json(); and the code is running. But I don't know why we dont need to return the response.json

Comment: @Shinichi1988 oh! Got it.. My bad.. It's because you are not sending JSON data from your api. You are only sending back string. Sorry that I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

if you separated client and server side,
using `<Redirect to='/home' />` 
react-router-dom on the client side

Comment: where should I put <Redirect to='/home' />?, I tried to put in Button, and it gave an error

Comment: @Shinichi1988 I couldn't see you already put `this.props.history.push('/home');` and still not working? can you see the defined routes?